# Python list indices must be integers or slices, not str when making a list of a list

Tags: python, pandas

I am using Python 3 and pandas and I would like to make a list within a list, by iterating over a list of data frames and pulling out indexes that match my criteria.  I am getting the error "list indices must be integers or slices, not str".
     I think the function works fine but the for loop does not.
     I need my function to read a column in a dataframe, find values that are less than or equal to 0.05 (in column 5 - titled 'P>|z|'), and create a list of the indexes that match that criteria.

```
def list_of_new_variables(maker_df):
    # Create a list with only significant p values
    newlist = list(make_results[make_results['P>|z|']<=acceptable_p_value].index)[0:]    
    return newlist


newlist = []
for maker_df in make_results:
    newlist.append(list_of_new_variables(maker_df))
```

The result should be a list of indexes that match the criteria within a list for each dataframe.

Here's my samples:
[data to find indexes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFwXb.png) [dataframes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbVJ2.png) [make_results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjIAc.png)

Edit

There full error is:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 10, in 
>       make_variables_refined.append(list_of_new_variables(make_results))
>
> File "", line 3, in
>   list_of_new_variables
>       newlist = list(make_results[make_results['P>|z|']<=acceptable_p_value].index)[0:]
>
> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Another edit:
Have tried the code for simplicity and also gets the error "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str".  I also tried using a column reference instead of the name of the column ('P>|z|') and it returned the same error.

```
make_variables_refined = []
for maker_df in make_results:
    make_variables_refined.append(make_results[int(make_results['P>|z|'])<=acceptable_p_value].index[0:])
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 3, in 
>       make_variables_refined.append(make_results[int(make_results['P>|z|'])<=acceptable_p_value].index[0:])
>
> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Answer (score 0):

Indices must be integers. Make the indice an integer:

```
def list_of_new_variables(maker_df):
    # Create a list with only significant p values
    newlist = list(make_results[make_results['P>|z|']<=acceptable_p_value].index)[0:]    
    return newlist


newlist = []
for maker_df in make_results:
    newlist.append(list_of_new_variables(int(maker_df)))
```

Comment: Thanks Tom, then I get the error: TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'

Comment: That means maker_df is a list. You cannot use a list as an index. Try using an item of the maker_df list as an index. E.g. maker_df[0].

Comment: Also just tried within the function as well but that got the same error list(make_results[make_results['P>|z|']<=acceptable_p_value].index.astype(str))[0:]

Answer (score 0):

when you reference and index within a list, the index must be in integer form. In your case; i believe the error is in this line:

```
newlist = list(make_results[make_results['P>|z|']<=acceptable_p_value].index)[0:]
```

the value in the square brackets should be an integer

try:

```
newlist = list(make_results[int(make_results['P>|z|')]<=acceptable_p_value].index)[0:]
```

Comment: That makes sense.  I moved the ) over to after the ] as it was not working and it is still throwing TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str.

Comment: Line 10 - both times (with both my original code and adding 'int' in line 4).

Comment: I just added the traceback to my original post.

Comment: i think i found it, the error is raised when you ask for the `'P>|z|'`index of the make_results list. As i am not quite sure what `make_reults['P>|z|']` is trying to achieve, i am not sure i can help you... maybe try replacing 'P>|z|' with the column number that you are referencing, i think you said it was 5 in your original post

Comment: That is the name of the column.  I tried replacing it with [:,4] and got the same error.

Comment: when you ask for a column in python, it must be done by the number, in integer form. Try replacing it with [4] or [5]

Answer (score 0):

`make_results` is a list of datafarmes. In Line 3, it is accessed via `make_results['P>|z|']`. This produces the error.
In your case, the goal is to find the indices associated with the records having a P>|z| value less than or equal to 0.05. Therefore, Line 10 should be

```
newlist = list(make_df[make_df['P>|z|']<=acceptable_p_value].index)[:]
```

Comment: That still gets the error: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I just dropped the variables from the original dataframe using:

```
for datas in make_results:
    datas.drop(datas.loc[datas['P>|z|'] > .05].index, inplace=True)
```